# How to grasp the data type Pair in dolphindb?

Tags: math, range, intervals, dolphindb

According to the manual of dolphindb,the range is upper bound exclusive of Pair,but when I test this data type:

```
print a[1:3];
for(s in 1:3){print s};          
print  3 in 1:3;
```

Output:

```
[1,2]
1
2
1
```

I think "upper bound exclusive" means open interval at the upper bound, why does `3 in 1:3` return 1?  How to grasp it?

Answer (score 0):

In DolphinDB, `pair` itself is just a special vector that contains two elements with identical type. So when you evaluate the expression 3 in 1:3, just check if 3 in vector [1,3]. Of course it returns 1 (true).

When a pair is used as an index of a vector, the upper bound is exclusive.